# AWS CLI filename search: only look inside a specific folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is there a way to *not* look through the entire bucket when searching for a filename?

We have millions of files so each search like this one takes **minutes**:

`aws s3api list-objects --bucket XXX --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'tokens.json')]"`

I can also make the key contain the folder name, but that doesn't speed things up at all:

`aws s3api list-objects --bucket XXX --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'folder/tokens.json')]"`

Comment: Maintain a separate index of all your S3 objects, or consider searching the S3 Inventory output (if it's OK that the inventory is taken once per day so is not 'live').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `prefix` option. You have to use this option not the query syntax because the query is applied after the list object occurs. See the details in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html).

Comment: Yep that did it. Immediately returns now, so the perfect solution if you know which folder to look in: `aws s3api list-objects --bucket XXX --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'file.json')]" --prefix "folder/subfolder"` Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are regularly searching for objects within an Amazon S3 with a large number of objects, you could consider using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a regular CSV listing of the objects in the bucket.